# How to read from text file and insert content into table in Oracle Apex?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Is there a way to read data from a text file and insert the contents into a table in Oracle Apex? probably something like APEX_DATA_PARSER.

Comment: Where is the text file?  If the file is on the client machine, for example, you could certainly create an APEX page where a user chooses the file to upload and `apex_data_parser` is used to parse the uploaded file.  But I have no idea whether that is the situation you're in.

Comment: The user will upload the file by clicking on a file upload item, this will be stored in a table where I will store all the uploaded text files. That part is done, now I am trying to read from any of the text files and store that data in a table.

Comment: Ok.  Then ‘apex_data_parser’ would appear to be the package you want.  What have you tried?  What error are you getting?  What isn’t working?

Comment: It works just fine, I thought it was limited to XML, JSON, CSV and XLSX files but it also works for text files. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to manually write the code using apex_data_parser. It's possible to create a data load definition which will then load the data into a collection (or table I believe) for you to work with. Almost no coding necessary.